# WinUI 3 app won't start after packaged and installing with .MSIX

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3, winui, msix

today I finished my application and wanted to build it, the choice fell on the standard msix package. After I assembled the application and launched it, it immediately crashed without even initializing. [Here is the event viewer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tEMi.png)

[here is the visual studio debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP5Y7.png)

I tried setting values

```
    <WindowsPackageType>MSIX</WindowsPackageType>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

​​in .csproj

Comment: Don't use (funky) images, paste texts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: There is an issue with one of your controls. Disable all (maybe on mainpage) then enable 1 at the time until your find the culprit.